# Submit button not saving my subscriber Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a website and I want to add a subscribe button to get email from users to send them some information but when I enter the email address and press the submit button, the User information won't save.

When I create an user into the rails console by doing:

```
Subscriber.create!(email: "test@example.com")
```

it actually saves the user information:

```
Subscriber Create (22.7ms)  INSERT INTO "subscribers" ("email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test@example.com"], ["created_at", "2019-06-17 11:00:06.853545"], ["updated_at", "2019-06-17 11:00:06.853545"]]], ["updated_at", "2019-06-17 11:00:06.853545"]]
```

but not when registering it from the form.

index.html.erb

```
<form class="form form-cta mt-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row gutter-0">
      <div class="col-8">
        <%= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Votre email", class: "form- 
        control form-control-rounded" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <%= f.submit :Sabonner, class: "btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-block" %>
      </div>
    </div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</form>
```

statics_controller.rb

```
class StaticsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :subscribers
  root to: 'statics#index'
end
```

subscribers_controller.rb

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new subscriber_params
    if @subscriber.save  
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Namsté !'
    else
        redirect_to root_path, alert: 'test'
  end


  private

  def subscriber_params
      params.require(:subscriber).permit(:email)
  end

end
```

Rails console:

```
Processing by StaticsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"balbalbla==", "subscriber"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com"}, "commit"=>"Sabonner"}
  Rendering statics/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered statics/index.html.erb within layouts/application (29.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 188ms (Views: 129.2ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)
```

I expect when I go into the console to get all my Subscribers but none of them are saved.
Do you have any ideas where this can come from?

Thanks

Comment: What's the rendered HTML? Seems like a path issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect `form_for url`.
Just check your routes via `rake -T` command. Check it for POST route to you subcriber create action. You should use it as your form action.

Submit action handled by your `StaticsController#index` action instead of `SubscribersController#create`.

Change your form code like so:

```
<form class="form form-cta mt-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row gutter-0">
      <div class="col-8">
        <%= form_for @subscriber, url: subscriber_path, method: :post do |f| %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Votre email", class: "form- 
        control form-control-rounded" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <%= f.submit :Sabonner, class: "btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-block" %>
      </div>
    </div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. what do you mean by
_Submit action handled by your StaticsController#index action instead of SubscribersController#create._?

Comment: @RemyAu Hi. Take a look to your form html code. Which action parameter (I talk about url) you see in <form> tag? It's the endpoint, there your form data will be send. More at [form_for helper documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for).